# No of trees can be constructed from given Inorder/Preorder/Postorder traversal

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

I know one cannot construct a tree without having both Inorder and Preorder/postorder traversals. Because for a given (only Inorder/Preorder/postorder) there could be a possibility of generating more number of trees. Are there any algorithms or mechanism one can compute the number of unique trees from a given (only Inorder/Preorder/postorder traversal).

```
Eg : a b c d e f g this is my Inorder traversal.
```

How many unique trees that can be constructed with the given Inorder traversal.

I tried them is google but none of the explanations are clear

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: `one cannot construct a tree without having both Inorder and Preorder/postorder traversals` that is one bold statement: 
Given keys *unique in the subtree they root* in *preorder* (equivalently *postorder*) and information about their sequence from left to right (explicitly or by order (*search tree*)), one can unambiguously reconstruct a tree. (Come to think of it, this seems to need a restriction to *binary tree* (implied with *inorder*).)

Comment: (I think it possible *with no two equal keys parent and child* is sufficient - finding a linear construction looks a challenge.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the algorithm is as follows:

Let, `P(N)` denote the number of trees possible with `N` nodes. Let the indexes of the nodes be `1,2,3,...`

Now, lets pick the root of the tree. Any of the given `N` nodes can be the root. Say node `i` has been picked as root. Then, all the elements to the left of `i` in the inorder sequence must be in the `left sub-tree`. Similarly, to the right.

So, total possibilities are: `P(i-1)*P(N-i)`

In the above expression `i` varies from `1 to N`.

Hence we have,

```
P(N) = P(0)*P(N-1) + P(1)*P(N-2) + P(2)*P(N-3)....
```

The base cases will be:

```
P(0) = 1 
P(1) = 1
```

Thus this can be solved by using `Dynamic Programming`.

Answer (score 2):

Note that a particular traversal is just a way of labeling the nodes in a tree, so that the number of possible binary trees is the same for any two traversals of the same length. The number of binary trees with `n` nodes is given by the `n-1`st [Catalan number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Answer (score 0):

The formula

(2n)!/ (n)!(n+1)!

OR

2n * C(n) / (n+1)

gives the number of possible binary trees for any given INORDER/PREORDER/POSTORDER traversal.